# Error accediendo a una clase desde otra

Tags: java, matemáticas

Estoy intentando hacer un programa llamado QuadraticTester que, usando otra clase, llamada Quadratic, me permita calcular una función cuadrática. Para ello, le pido al usuario que introduzca los coeficientes A, B y C. Todo funciona correctamente a la hora de compilarlos, el problema surge cuando quiero ejecutarlos. Me aparece el siguiente error en el Simbolo del Sistema:

[image: Error en el simbolo del sistema]

El programa Quadratic es el siguiente:

```
class Quadratic{

double a, b, c;

String armarEcuacion(double a, double b, double c){
    String ecuacion = ("Y = " + a + "x^2 + " + b + "x + " + c);
    return ecuacion;

}}
```

El programa QuadraticTester es el siguiente:

```
public class QuadraticTester{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Quadratic cuad1 = new Quadratic();

    double a = Scanner.getDouble("Ingrese un valor para el coeficiente A: \n");
    double b = Scanner.getDouble("Ingrese un valor para el coeficiente B: \n");
    double c = Scanner.getDouble("Ingrese un valor para el coeficiente C: \n");

    System.out.println(cuad1.armarEcuacion(a, b, c));
}
```

}

No sé muy bien que significan estos errores , ni cómo solucionarlos. Espero que se haya entendido el problema, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un poco embarazoso ya que estaba escribiendo el comando java de manera erronea:

Estaba ejecutandolo así:

```
C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop>java QuadraticTester.java
```

Pero la forma correcta es:

```
C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop>java QuadraticTester
```

(sin el .java al final del nombre del archivo)

Aún así, muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas y amabilidad!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tus variables en la clase Quadratic

```
double a, b, c;
```

estan demas

y a tu metodo hazlo publico para que puedas acceder a el asi quedaria:

```
class Quadratic{

public String armarEcuacion(double a, double b, double c){
    String ecuacion = ("Y = " + a + "x^2 + " + b + "x + " + c);
    return ecuacion;

}}
```

Eso es todo...
y ahora si quieres acceder a propiedades de una clase, no basta con double, int o string, tienes que ponerlos staticos segun sea tu necesidad claro

```
static double a, b, c;
```

y los llamas asi previamente importado en otra clase:

```
import paquete.Quadratic;
public class QuadraticTester{
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Quadratic.a = Scanner.getDouble("Ingrese un valor para el coeficiente A: \n");
    Quadratic.b = Scanner.getDouble("Ingrese un valor para el coeficiente B: \n");
    Quadratic.c = Scanner.getDouble("Ingrese un valor para el coeficiente C: \n");


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tanto la clase `Quadratic`, como su método `armarEcuacion` deberían ser públicos:

```
public class Quadratic{ 
   ....

   public String armarEcuacion(double a, double b, double c){ 
       ....
```